# Model transparency depth issue in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xna, transparency

Hey guys I've looked around and I could not find any understandable solutions for a beginner C# programmer like myself.

I have a model (tree) for my project on Visual Studio C#, the tree uses planes for the leaves, and I have textured the planes with an image of a leaf with a transparent background on Blender. I have made the materials transparent and the texture accept alpha, but when I import this into my game, the leaves are visible but the transparency cuts through the tree branches and displays everything but the branches behind it.

[image: Screenshot]

This is my basic draw method, could someone please give me a method that invokes alpha blending or whatever it is I need for the transparency to work properly? I really don't want to have to read an entire book on transparency depth..

```
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.FogEnabled = true;
                effect.FogStart = 70;
                effect.FogEnd = 100;
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.World = camera.world;
                effect.View = view;
                effect.Projection = projection;
            }
            mesh.Draw();
```

Comment: What technology do you use? DirectX? XNA? OpenGL? Are the leaves semi-transparent or either transparent or opaque? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I cannot send an image as I don't have enough reputation apparently... I am using XNA. I'm not too sure how the transparencies work so I can't answer that, but in Blender I changed the material properties to Z Transparency, and made it 100% transparent, applying a .bmp leaf image with entirely transparent back image.. if thats any help?

Comment: Pick any image hoster to upload the screenshot and someone will insert it into the post. What do you mean with transparent bmp? A bmp file does not support transparency. How have you exported your model?

Comment: http://i57.tinypic.com/9k2s14.png
I tried both .bmp and .png, on blender and they both functioned the same way. I imported the model into blender and exported as fbx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your leaves don't have any semi-transparent regions, you can solve this problem with alpha-testing. To do so, you have to use the `AlphaTestEffect` to render your tree (or implement alpha-testing in the pixel shader). In earlier versions of XNA there were alpha test render states. But these have been removed in version 4.0

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm not very fond of the function, could you give an example of the code please?

Comment: You just need to change the effect type. You probably use the `BasicEffect`. Convert that to the `AlphaTestEffect`.

Comment: I eventually figured what you meant and I am on track now thank-you!